# how to make Pyarrow CSV writer not add double quotes around strings

Tags: python, csv, pyarrow

I am writing an arrow table to csv like this.

```
import pyarrow.csv as csv
csv.write_csv(table, 'myfile.csv', csv.WriteOptions(include_header=True,delimiter='|'))
```

but when I look at the exported file every string type in the table has double quotes around it. I have written this table to csv with pandas and the double quotes are not there. Is there any way to avoid this with the pyarrow csv writer?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.write_csv.html) there's a `write_options` keyword argument. However, it looks like there's no option to diable the double quotes ([see here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.WriteOptions.html#pyarrow.csv.WriteOptions)).  An option to come to mind would be to use another csv writer (e.g. pandas', or open the file again and use regex to remove the quotes).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.